# Add values to a PlotLabel; use text characters for PlotMarkers in DiscretePlot3D

Tags: plotting

I have a plot like this:

```
Table[Plot[a*x^2/4, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLabel -> "a="  a], {a, 1, 5, 1}]
```

I want to label the plots as `a=1`, `a=2`, ..., but *Mathematica* labels them as `a=`, `2a=`, ....

How can I solve this problem?

I also have another problem:

```
DiscretePlot3D[2 x + y, {x, {1, 4, .2}}, {y, {2, 6, .2}}, 
   Filling -> None, PlotMarkers -> {"Sphere", .01}]
```

Why I can not use plot markers such as `*`, `\[FilledSquare]`, ... in this plot?

Comment: As to the "why" part of the question -- it is interesting that `PlotMarkers` isn't even mentioned in the More Information section of `DiscretePlot3D` nor is 3D Plot usage described in the `PlotMarkers` documentation. The usage `DiscretePlot3D` example demonstrates "Sphere" and "Point". Clearly inadequately documented.

Comment: Is this  your another account http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1894/soodeh  ?  To benefit from this site it would be advantageous to register your account.

Comment: As Artes says, please consider registering your account . You'll be able to participate better in the community and also be able to login from anywhere and carry forward your points. If the above account is indeed yours, please register your current account and add the login credentials you used for the other one to confirm ownership and flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

The PlotLabel needs to be a string, so for instance:

```
 Table[Plot[a*x^2/4, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLabel -> "a=" ~~ ToString[a]], {a, 1, 5, 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `StringForm[]`:

   ```
   Table[Plot[a*x^2/4, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLabel -> StringForm["a=`1`", a]], {a, 1, 5, 1}]
   ```
2. You could make a substitution into the plot graphics object to solve the problem:

   ```
   DiscretePlot3D[2 x + y, {x, {1, 4, .2}}, {y, {2, 6, .2}}, 
                  Filling -> None, PlotMarkers -> "Point"] /. 
   Point[pts : {__?VectorQ}] :> (Text["\[FilledSquare]", #, {0, -1}] & /@ pts)
   ```

   [image: 3D discrete plot with squares]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful answer.

Comment: @J.M. Your trick for `DiscretePlot3D ` is sneaky clever.